# What are `gom-*miner` processes?

Tags: process

I've got few running processes that eat up all my resources, blocked network and disk I/O, after some time whole computer froze, I couldn't even go to classical non-gui terminal.

I've found them using `top` while I had time, and it was everything starting with `gom-`:

```
$pgrep gom
4352 gom-gdata-miner
4364 gom-media-serve
4427 gom-flickr-mine
4449 gom-facebook-mi
```

However, pacman says something different about gom, nothing about miner:

```
$ pacman -Ss gom
extra/gom 0.2.1-1 [installed]
    A GObject to SQLite object mapper
extra/kdegames-bovo 14.12.3-1 (kde kdegames)
    A Gomoku like game for two players
extra/pangomm 2.34.0-1 [installed]
    C++ bindings for pango
extra/pangomm-docs 2.34.0-1
    Developer documentation for pangomm
```

Comment: Any ideas on disabling these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gom-` stands for [`gnome-online-miners`](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-online-miners) and they `Crawl[s] through your online content`.